# How to change the order of confusion matrix values

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I used the following code to create confusion matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(df['diabetes'], df['predictions'])
cm
```

It shows the output as following:

[image]

But I want to get the following output:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the labels and predictions are 0s and 1s, inverting all of the values like this should give the desired behavior

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

cm = confusion_matrix(np.abs(df['diabetes']-1), np.abs(df['predictions']-1))
cm
```